# How to use Lightroom and Photoshop Elements together?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop-elements

I know the catalog cannot be shared between these two programs, but what is a good way to have them coexist together?  It seems like I would have to have a separate copy of my photos that each program would use.  I use Lightroom, but looking at picking up Photoshop Elements and Premiere 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install both programs on the same computer, you can open the images in Photoshop Elements directly from within Lightroom. See instructions [here](http://www.tipsquirrel.com/index.php/2010/09/lightroom-to-photoshop-and-back-another-way/) or google "lightroom open in photoshop".

The advantage of this (compared to exporting the images, then opening in Phososhop) is that the *.PSD files are automatically accessible from Lightroom's catalog, and can (optionally) be stacked with the original RAW images, making your workflow a lot simpler to manage. You can also add metadata to the linked PSD files.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop Lightroom does basically everything a photographer would want as compared to what Elements can do. **If there is a specific feature you want in Elements, just export from Lightroom as a JPG and make your edits in Elements, then pull it back into Lightroom.** No specific workflow is needed.

Personally, for photography I rarely use Photoshop any longer, as Lightroom will do about 95% of what I need to fully ingest/asset manage/backup/edit/print a wedding shoot.

Comment: actually there's no need to export - you can open the image directly from LR using *> Photo > Edit In > Photoshop*

Comment: @Sleed - I call that exporting, but I guess you could argue it isn't. It does save you the step of finding the file in Elements in this case. So yea, good call.

Comment: yeah, it means you don't need to do the final step of "pull it back into Lightroom" - if you simply hit Save in Photoshop it'll show up in the LR catalog.